# How to customize TokenObtainPairSerializer's fields

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

By default TokenObtainPairSerializer takes in username and password

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view())
]
```

```json
{
    "username": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "password": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

I want the fields to be a singular phone_number instead, so I tried editing the serializer

```py
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    
    phone_number = serializers.CharField(max_length=10)

class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

But this instead adds phone_number as a required field instead of making phone_number the **only** required field. How can I remove username and password as required fields?

```json
{
    "phone_number": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "username": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "password": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create abstract base user and add phone_number as username field:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
 email = models.EmailField(
    verbose_name='email address',
    max_length=255,
    unique=True,
)
 phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
 date_of_birth = models.DateField()
 is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
 is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

 objects = MyUserManager()

 USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
 REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
```

set user in settings.py file:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user_app.MyUser'
```

for more info to create a custom user model [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-django-contrib-admin)

Comment: I've got a custom user model. I'm trying to figure out how to change the required authentication fields on TokenObtainPairSerializer

Comment: what is your USERNAME_FIELD in the user model?